Transactions executed in Spring using external Tomcat twice faster than Spring embeded Tomcat
A simple Spring application that uses standard Hikari connector and Eclipselink as JPA provider takes double time (aprox) if executed using embeded Tomcat. I also tried hibernate with similar result.
@Entity
@Table(name = "chats")
public class Chat{
    
    @Id    
    private String  id;

    public Chat() {    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}


//Repo
public interface ChatRepository extends JpaRepository<Chat, String> {
}


Configuration:

@Configuration
public class EclipseLinkJpaConfigurationHikari {

    
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan("project");        
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter());
        hace que selecciones uno de persitance.xml
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("eclipselink.weaving", "false");
        properties.put("eclipselink.logging.level", "INFO");
        properties.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation", "none");
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

}

Controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TestController {

    private final ChatRepository chatRepository;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public TestController(ChatRepository chatRepository) {
        this.chatRepository = chatRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for( int x=1 ; x <1500;x++){
            List<Chat> chats = chatRepository.findAll();
            Chat c = chats.get(0);
        }

        long time = (System.currentTimeMillis() - t);
        return t + "ms";
    }

}

application.properties
spring.application.name=TestConnection


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.provider_class=com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=yyy
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=50000
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=300000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=900000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=10
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=ConnPool
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=select 1 from dual

spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.cachePrepStmts=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.prepStmtCacheSize=250
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useServerPrepStmts=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useLocalSessionState=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.rewriteBatchedStatements=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.cacheResultSetMetadata=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.cacheServerConfiguration=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.elideSetAutoCommits=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.maintainTimeStats=false

logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=TRACE

spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource

If I execute this request, the processing times are:
External tomcat -> 494ms, 232msms, 217ms, 193ms, 198ms, 214ms, 155ms, 155ms, 107ms (stabilizes around 100ms any further request )
Embedded tomcat -> 363ms, 200ms, 189ms , 207ms, 201ms, 194ms, 193ms, 185ms, 192ms
(stabilizes around 195ms any further request )
What is going on? I am using the same configuration, same tomcat version, same libraries from gradle. After first request cache starts working but it seems to work better for external tomcat. In general, the performance for any request that access the dabase is twice faster when using external tomcat.
Note: if I remove @Transactional from controller's method, processing time is even larger, from 200ms to 280ms (embedded) and from 100ms to 150ms (external tomcat).

You aren't using Hikari but rather Tomcat JDBC Pool. How did you use Embedded Tomcat? Is this a Spring Boot application or not?

It is Spring boot application. I use embedded tomcat by including:
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
Why do you say I am using Tomcat JDBC Pool?

Because that is what your dataSource method is returning and using and you aren't using the Spring pre-configured Hikari JDBC pool by specifying spring.datasource properties (even if they would be there they are useless as they are ignored as you specify the datasource and then auto config backs out).

Sorry, you are right, I updated my question with the "correct?" configuration. I get the same result in any case, triggering the same method several times while running tomcat external must activate some kind of cache that reduces the execution time as I mentioned in my question.

The correct configuration would be a configuration with just a LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean, the database configuration would be in the application.properties using the spring.datasource properties. This will let Spring auto configure the datasource and JPA transaction mamager. I also don't see the benefit of injecting the EntityManager into the controller. I also wonder how you are running both solutions. Are you re-using the same artifact? Running from an IDE or how are you doing this for the embedded tomcat part.

I updated my question and changed configuration by using application.properties. I have already tried this  (I have tried everything :( ). To run the application with external tomcat I dont use the same artifact because I didnt know you could do that, I use intellij, I made a new artififact (web application exploded), added all the same libraries and executed on external tomcat of same version.

So you aren't using the same artifact, so basically you are comparing apples and oranges. Don't use spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query it will automatically use JDBC4 connection validation. What you should do is use the same artifact, how to do that is explained here. You will now get a WAR file that you can run with java -jar your.war to use the internal tomcat or deploy it to the external one. You should be at least comparing the same artificat.

Additionally you shouldn't set spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.provider_class either and what is it you want to use for MySQL as you are specifying 2 different dialects.

You were RIGHT. After some sweating I managed to make the war and ejecute it on tomcat container and as standalone application. In both cases performance was similar and it was as good as it was when running external tomcat from intellij. The next question would be... what is that makes Spring Boot application in Intellij to run slower?

@M.Deinum I found out the reason why the performance was worse, I awsered my own question. Thanks for your help.

After several days of investigation I found out the reason why the application had different performance while using external tomcat or the configuration provided by Intellij Idea.

After enabling the option Disable launch optimization (-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1), the performance is as good as executed by external Tomcat.

There's a few things that come to mind supposing you are running on the same computer with your tests.
First, are you running the same JVM with the external Tomcat as you are with the embedded? Sometimes it is easy to oversee what actual JVM is running when running with the Spring uber jar.
Secondly, are you using the same memory and CPU settings? If you didn't specify them, the embedded version may have completely different defaults than a fresh install of Tomcat which has different defaults.
Third, compare JVM settings such as your garbage collector or active processor count. Different JVMs have different configurations which could affect things slightly so you should double check if your Tomcat is running the JVM with some of these extra -XX settings.
Fourth, check Spring Boot's server properties as some of them may be defaulted differently than the Tomcat instance.
There shouldn't be any reason they run differently as they implement the same type of code so I would bet it is something JVM related.


It is the same computer.
It is the same JVM: 21. I set it up in build.gradle, I also double checked by retrieving System.getProperty("java.version") value.
JVM options is similar for both: -Xms1g -Xmx2g -XX:+UseG1GC
About server properties, I have tried different configurations but I havent found anything
What really puzzles me is the fact that the application ran in external tomcat reduces the time needed to compute the method from about 500ms to 100ms after several requests.

